# How can I deploy WCF Service without IIS in XP?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, deployment, windows-xp

**How can I deploy WCF Service without IIS in XP?** (pretty much straightforward)

The service will only be consumed by a local network in a Windows App, has a security of a *Custom Username and Password Validator* in a wsHttpBinding.

My service codes are in C#, Framework 4.0, build in Visual Studio 2010 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it as a self hosted windows service, there is a write up on it on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using [System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx).

In essence:

```
IMyContract instance = new MyService();
var host = new ServiceHost(instance, "net.tcp://localhost:1234/MyEndpoint");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I deploy a WCF Service in XP?

Comment: By putting the above code in an application you write, like a Winforms app, a Windows service, or a console application. ServiceHost exposes an endpoint for your service without IIS.

Comment: You've accepted the answer without a code sample. The link in the other post just uses ServiceHost.

Comment: @tomfanning - The link in the other answer is a complete example, with code.  Your code snippet is one of three overloads for the `ServiceHost` constructor, and in particular it's the one to create a singleton - which may not be what OP is looking for.  Both your answer and the other answer utilize ServiceHost to host the service.